# Find a word after a keyword, then, paste it after a different keyword.

Tags: python

For example, I have a multiple strings in a tex file that looks something like:

> "The conditions Heat_Transfer blah blah blah BC"

Using python I would like to:

1. Find the word after "conditions" (in this case Heat_Transfer)
2. Then paste Heat_Transfer after BC.

The output string should look like:

> "The conditions Heat_Transfer blah blah blah BC Heat_Transfer"

The keywords conditions and BC stay the same for each string, but Heat_Transfer changes.

Comment: is BC always at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use re to find both and replace keeping all whitespace:

```
s =  "The conditions Heat_Transfer blah blah blah   BC some other text"
con = re.compile(r"(?<=\bconditions\b)\s+(\S+)")
bc = re.compile(r"(\bBC\b)")
m = con.search(s)
if m:
    print(bc.sub(r"\1"+m.group(), s)) 

The conditions Heat_Transfer blah blah blah   BC Heat_Transfer some other text
```

If you were going down the splitting route then you can get the indexes in a single pass:

```
keywords = {"conditions","BC"}
words = s.split(" ")
inds = (i for i, w in enumerate(words) if w in keywords)

a,b = next(inds), next(inds)
print(a, b)
```

Then simply join where apppropriate:

```
w = words[a+1]
print(" ".join(["BC " + w if ind == b else wrd for ind,wrd in enumerate(words)]))


The conditions Heat_Transfer blah blah blah   BC Heat_Transfer some other text
```

Answer (score 2):

You first need to split the given string on spaces using the `.split()` method on string, then you find the index of the keyword and next you place the string next to that index at the end of the string, by simply concatenating the word to the initial string with a space in between.

```
sentence = "The conditions Heat_Transfer blah blah blah BC" 
keyword = "conditions"

split_sentence = sentence.split()
sentence+=" "+split_sentence[split_sentence.index(keyword)+1]

print sentence
>>> The conditions Heat_Transfer blah blah blah BC Heat_Transfer
```

Alternatively, you may do all the concatenating operations on the `list` itself and later join the elements of the string with a space using `.join()` method.

```
split_sentence.append(split_sentence[split_sentence.index(keyword)+1])
print " ".join(split_sentence)
```

Comment: This assumes that the second keyword is at the end.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi just changed my handle anyways, which second keyword are you referring to ?

Comment: *Find a word after a keyword, then, paste it after a different keyword.*

Comment: Oh I mis-interpreted the question. Sorry @MalikBrahimi :) your's solution is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

With the assumption that you are sure that your keyword 'conditions' exist.

```py
str_ = "The conditions Heat_Transfer blah blah blah BC"

list_ = str_.split(" ")
str_ = str_+" "+list_[list_.index("conditions")+1]
```

Otherwise:

```py
str_ = "The conditions Heat_Transfer blah blah blah BC"
try:
   list_ = str_.split(" ")
   str_ = str_+" "+list_[list_.index("conditions")+1]
except:
   pass
```

Comment: Needs a space between the original string and the added string (`str_+' '+...`).

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `str_.split(" ")` will return only words so if there is `somethingconditions`  `list_.index("conditions")` won't detect it

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think that PO is sure that the keyword exist. any way, I will add a `try/catch` block

Answer (score 1):

```
string = string.split() # split string into list

a = string.index(keyword1) # find index of 1st
b = string.index(keyword2) # find index of 2nd

string.insert(b + 1, string[a + 1]) # insert word
string = ' '.join(string) # join list into string
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It's assumed to be a sentence, so only single spaces.

Comment: I'm joining the list with single spaces between every word. When you're writing up a paper do you put three spaces between some and two between others? No there are only single spaces between words in a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with regex:

```
import re 

str = "The conditions Heat_Transfer blah blah blah BC"

match = re.search('conditions\s([a-zA-z_\-0-9]+)', str)

word = match.group(1)

print str + ' ' + word
```